# Laravel 6 behind proxy always return 404

Tags: laravel, nginx, proxy

I have one nginx server running wordpress at https://example.com (I'll call this Server A)
Then, I want to host laravel app in another nginx server at https://example.com/laravel(I'll call this Server B)
This Server B is configured with https://laravel.example.com

In Server A, I have the following config.

```
location /laravel/ {
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_pass https://subdomain.example.com;
}
```

In Server B, the following is the config.

```
server {
    root /var/www/Saskatchewan/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php =404;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    access_log      /var/www/example.com/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/example.com/error.log;
}
server {
    if ($host = learning.tieng-viet.jp) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

The problem is that when I access the laravel powered site(https://example.com/laravel),
it returns 404(Not nginx but Laravel 404).
I tried accessing some static files too, but it's the same result.

I was able to confirm that the request is indeed reaching Server B.
And 404 page is generated by Laravel.

When I access the site with the following, it works perfectly fine.
https://subdomain.example.com

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks

UPDATE
Static files are not served either. It returns 404 Laravel not found error page.

Comment: Does it return `404` laravel default error page or Nginx error page?

Comment: @user8555937 Laravel 404 page

Answer (score 0):

First, configure your website default address in `.env`. Clear application cache after doing so: `php artisan config:cache`

Then use routing to allow access from different domains:

```
// by domain
Route::domain('example.com')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/test', function(){
        return response('another domain');
    });
});

// relative to default APP_URL
Route::get('/test', function(){
    return response('default APP_URL');
});
```

If you want to duplicate routes for more domains, use the following concept:

```
$routes = function() {
    Route::get('/test', function(){
        return response('This route is duplicated for both domains');
    });
}

Route::domain('example.com')->group($routes);
Route::domain('laravel.example.com')->group($routes);
```

Hope this helps.

---

Btw, make sure your Nginx proxy outputs to laravel server the correct `HTTP_*` headers as in `$_SERVER`. A comprehensive list with them can be found here https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. APP_URL is configured to https://example.com/laravel. Still I get 404 error. I changed APP_URL to https://laravelexample.com/. Neither of them work. I made sure I cleared the cache as well.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Also, static files cannot be accessed either. It returns Laravel 404 page when accessed from https://example.com/laravel like https://example.com/laravel/js/app.js

Answer (score 0):

What might be the issue is the order of your `location /laravel/` statement in server A. Make sure no other `location` rule with a more generic matcher is before this one in the nginx config.

Bad:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location ~ /(.*) {
    ...
  }

  location /laravel/ {
    ...
  }
}
```

Good:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location /laravel/ {
    ...
  }

  location ~ /(.*) {
    ...
  }
}
```

For more details, have a look at [how an nginx request is being processed](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

By the way, not sure why you make `/laravel/` of server A a reverse proxy instead of a permanent redirect. Usability-wise, this would be better in my opinion.